# iOS: Resetting UIPickerView EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, exc-bad-access

I am using a PickerView to choose values and I want to reset it, (so it doesn't show the previous selection) after pressing a button.

The problem is I am always getting one of two errors, it changes from run to run with no apparent pattern.

Does anyone know what might cause the errors, respectively how to solve the problem?

Code:

```
NSString * chosen;
NSString * elemString;
NSMutableArray *secondTableArray ;
NSInteger p = 0;
@implementation LagerViewController
@synthesize requestObject;
@synthesize choosenDocKind;
@synthesize pickerView1;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    secondTableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    secondTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    secondTableView.bounces = YES;
    elemString = @"";
    choosenDocKind = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    [pickerView removeFromSuperview]; 
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(pickerViewItems != nil)
    {
        [pickerViewItems release];
        pickerViewItems = nil;
    } 
    if((indexPath.section == 1)&&(indexPath.row == 0))
    {
        NSString * temp = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",elemString] copy];
        NSString * tableString;
        if([temp length] == 0) {
             [secondTableArray removeAllObjects];
             [secondTableView reloadData];  
             elemString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ARTIKEL: %@ %@ %@", matchcode, quantity, choosenDocKind] copy];
             tableString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", matchcode, quantity, choosenDocKind] copy];

             // THESE 2 ROWS BELOW CAUSE THE ERRORS
             [pickerView reloadAllComponents];
             [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
        }
    }
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    [theTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - button events
- (IBAction)btnSubmitPVSelection:(id)sender
{
    if([choosenPrompt isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"DOCUMENT_REQUEST_LAGER_UM", nil)])
    {
        if(choosenDocKind != nil)
        {
            chosen = choosenDocKind;
            [choosenDocKind release];
            choosenDocKind = nil;
        }
        choosenDocKind = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[pickerViewItems objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]] retain];
    }
    [tvArchDocParam reloadData];
    if(choosenPrompt != nil)
    {
        [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        [choosenPrompt release];
        choosenPrompt = nil;
    }
    [pickerView reloadAllComponents];
    [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
}
```

.h

```
@interface ... {
    DocRequest *requestObject;
    NSArray *pickerViewItems;
    NSString *choosenPrompt;
    UITextView *matchtext;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tvArchDocParam;
    UIAlertController *actionSheet;
    UITableView *theTableView;
    IBOutlet UITableView *secondTableView;
}   
@property (nonatomic, retain)DocRequest* requestObject;
@property (nonatomic, retain)UIPickerView *pickerView1;
-(UITableViewCell*)getSelectorCell:(NSString*)CellIdentifier;
-(UITableViewCell*)getTextFieldCell:(NSString*)CellIdentifier;
-(void)showPickerView;
```

Errors:

```
1. Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
2. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason NSDictionaryM reloadAllComponents
```

Comment: how do you declare pickerView and where do you create it?

Comment: show how do you declare all you variables and you UIPickerViewDataSource  methods

Comment: once more —  show how you create pickerView1 and where do you show/hide it. show for example what do you do in - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
            viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
          forComponent:(NSInteger)component
          reusingView:(UIView *)view. Certanly reason of your crash is in memort management, probably because of pickerView or something related to show items in it. so more you show about it - more I can say you about crash

Answer (score 3):

First and most important — stop using manual memory management.

Second about crashes, looks like both crashes related and caused by the same issue (due to code you gave us, it's impossible to guess what exactly make app crash), obviously your pickerView was released somewhere before [pickerView reloadAllComponents]; was called.

It may be caused because of [pickerView removeFromSuperview]; in viewDidLoad for example if you pickerView is assign or something like that.

Comment: Should I post all the methods using the PickerView? And I am fairly certain the reasons you mentioned are not the ones causing the app to crash in this case.

Comment: I was also going to suggest that you move your globals to be properties of the class.